# I am build a common jar to be used by both spring boot and a J2EE application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a common project I'd like to import to both a spring boot application and a J2EE application. One of the Objects is a set of attributes set from parameters. In spring boot I'd like to use @Value to set them, for the non-spring platform I have to load the properties with code. I'd like to use the same object for both environments since it's use is pervasive. My attempts to use builders have failed because they inevitably get instantiated before the spring objects.

Who's done this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First: why do you differentiate between Spring Boot and J2EE? Spring Boot applications also can be run in a container. Second: Why is this so hard? You have to build a library that does not load it's own values, but gets all parameters from outside. I'd recommend constructor injection, and you can annotate your ctor with `@Inject`. This is understood both by J2EE and Spring. Also some code would be nice to see here for a proper answer, please add some minimal example for reproduction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hoped for something more elegant but maybe I'm spoiled by Spring Boot. I had to replace the @Autowired parameters class with a builder that implements  ApplicationContextAware. The setApplicationContext method will instantiate the parameters object if it gets executed (the builder class was loaded by Spring and is aware) or by the simple retrieval of parameters for a non-spring environment.